# ¿Como muestro una segunda forma/ventana en un CLR empty project (Visual Studio 2019)?

Tags: c++, windows-forms, windows, app

No he encontrado ningún tutorial en el que me ayude aprender windows forms en este estilo de project, es diferente al de C#, donde una de las líneas era:

`Form fh = formhija as Form;`

En este estilo de proyecto no tengo ni idea como eso se debería de "traducir"; ¿alguien que me pueda ayudar?